# How to use prototype in javascript thatinherit from string Object and implements custom function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a funtionas follow,

```
function revStr(s) {
    ns = '';

    for (i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    ns += s[i];
    alert(ns);
}
```

I have been asked to implement this using Prototype which I am totally unaware of in Javascript(I am a phpdeveloper:( )

I have to create an object that inherits from a string object . Which I think we can do something like this

```
var MyString= new string();
```

and then implement my function `revStr` using somethingcalled `Prototype` in javascript

Can anyone help me out in this .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you want to add `revStr()` to the `String.prototype`, so basically all strings can do `revStr()`.

You can implement the function to the string prototype by:

```
String.prototype.revStr = function(){
    ns = '';
    for (i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ns += this[i];
    alert(ns);
}
```

So you can use this function on any string afterwards like this:

```
'hello world'.revStr();
'fooobarrrr'.revStr();
```

Comment: Can youplease explain me bit about how this prototype works and what is it ?. @TaoPR

Comment: In JS, prototype of object holds the inheritable property of such object (in your case, string) just similar to a Class. The 'this' keyword refers to the instance of that object by default.

Comment: You add a new function to String.prototype. All instances of strings will have that method in place to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add string object a new prototype
    // property method revStr
    String.prototype.revStr = function () {
        var ns = '';
        for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ns += this[i];
        };

        return ns
    };
    // use it like this
    console.log("String".revStr());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.rev = function () {
    var s = this;

    ns = '';

    for (i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ns += s[i];
    alert(ns);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to create an object that inherits from a string object
>   ... implement my function revStr using somethingcalled **Prototype** in javascript

Thats simple. Simply make a  change to String.prototype

All String instances inherit from String.prototype. Functions available to the String prototype object are available to all String instances.

```
String.prototype.revStr = function(s){
    ns = '';

    for (i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    ns += s[i];
    alert(ns);
}
```

This way, if you do `var obj = new String()`, the newly created object `obj` will prototypically inherit the `revStr` method defined on `String.prototype` and calling `obj.revStr("abcd")` will return `"dcba"`

When it comes to inheritance, JavaScript only has one construct: objects. Each object has an internal link to another object called its *prototype*. When trying to access a property of an object, the property will not only be sought on the object but on the prototype of the object, the prototype of the prototype, and so on until either a property with a matching name is found or the end of the prototype chain is reached

You may read more about Prototypal inheritance from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)